# Redis MGET performance

Tags: python, redis

I am trying to load all the values in the redis database for which I am using mget(r.keys()) from redis library. There are close to 100k key,value pairs each of size ~40kb in the db. It is taking close to 38 seconds to do this on a windows machine with more than 64GB of RAM.

I have loaded 100k json dumped numpy arrays into the redis database and running the code shown below to capture the time taken to read the data.

```
import redis
import time
start=time.time()
r=redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost',port=6379,db=0)
test=r.mget(r.keys())
print(time.time()-start)
```

The time taken is ~38 seconds on a windows machine which has >50GB of free RAM. I checked the system performance during the runtime and there are no bottlenecks. I expected a faster read performance but can someone confirm if this is the expected behaviour or if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`r.keys()` is not recommended and should consider using `scan()` instead.

By calling `keys()` you're basically asking Redis to generate a list of all the keys and return them to the client, which is a long blocking operation.

Then, by calling `r.mget()` you send this all list of 100k keys back to Redis and ask it to generate a one big result of all the Hashes.

I would recommend you switch to use `scan()` and batch the results from Redis.
Last, once you move into batches in order to avoid waiting for each batch to return before you ask for the next batch you might want to use pipline.

Comment: Thanks. I used scan and pipeline both. There was not much difference in the the time taken when I used pipeline along with scan. However, when I used only scan the time taken reduced to 12 seconds. I have pasted the code I used for creating and executing the pipelines. Can the 12 seconds be optimised further?                                                            pipe=r.pipeline()
for key in r.scan_iter(count=50000) :
   pipe.get(key)
pipe.execute()                                                                                                         
Pipe is executed outside the loop